# Как в скрипте определить, когда игрок наводит курсор на 2д объект?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в скрипте определить, когда игрок наводит курсор на 2д объект. Будь то спрайт или что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью raycast. Пример кода из документации (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraRays.html)

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
      Transform objectHit = hit.transform;
        
       // Do something with the object that was hit by the raycast. 
}
```